# Is the phrase "proximity span" correct?

Tags: semantics

A span is the distance between two points in this case. For example, the span of a bridge from end to end. Is it correct semantically to say the span of a proximity or distance?

Comment: Robert is right, this question should be migrated. But fair warning: since it demonstrates no independent research, it will likely be closed. Short answer is "no": *proximity* is synonymous with *closeness*, and *closeness span* is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be correct. The relevant [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/span) of *span* is:

> The full extent of something from end to end; the amount of space that something covers

So it is normally used in reference to a particular object that has a size. Proximity and distance aren't objects that have sizes, they're quantities themselves, similar to span.

Put another way, the span of a bridge is the distance between its endpoints. It would be somewhat circular (or maybe just redundant), then, to refer to the span of the distance.